# How to remove subcategory in recursive function? asp.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am trying to delete subcategory from repeater using a link button. Currently, main category deleted but i cant delete subcaegory. Help me please...

```
    private void BindRepeater()
    {
        DataTable dtCategory = system.GetDataTable("Select * from TBLCATEGORIES where SubCategoryID="+CategoryID); 

        if (dtCategory.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            rpCategory.DataSource = dtCategory;
            rpCategory.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void OnDelete(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
    //Find the reference of the Repeater Item.
    RepeaterItem item = (sender as LinkButton).Parent as RepeaterItem;


    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Delete from TBLCATEGORIES where SubCategoryID="+CategoryID); 
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

            DeleteMsg.Visible = true;
        }
    }
    this.BindRepeater();
}
```

Comment: Does the problem occur only if the row that is deleted is the only row in the Repeater or does it also occur if there are several rows in the repeater?

Answer (score 0):

Please find  the code,hope this will help you:

```
   protected void rpCategory_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
            SqlConnection conn;
            SqlCommand comm;
            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ShqiptarConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

            conn.Open();

            if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
            {
            comm = new SqlCommand("Delete from TBLCATEGORIES where CategoryID=" + e.CommandArgument, conn);
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();
            DeleteMsg.Visible = true;

           //Rebind here: this.BindRepeater();
    }
```

Comment: Please go through the below reference                  [link] http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-Repeater-CRUD-Select-Insert-Edit-Update-and-Delete-in-Repeater-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx              we have a working example.

Comment: you  can write a function and call the function in your procedure.